# Changing the DateFormat on SharePoint site

Tags: 2010, localization

I want to change the DateFormat of a SharePoint site while NOT changing the sites current culture (en-US). This is per requirement as the site is for an international customer and they need to use the company standard date format which is dd/MM/yyyy for a short date string (instead the MM/dd/yyyy).

After a short investigation it seems rather complicated to achieve this in SharePoint 2010. Some people (http://dotnet.lv/blogs/antonsm/archive/2008/12/21/change-date-format-in-sharepoint.aspx) suggest to update the culture definition for the targeted locale (e.g. en-US) on the SharePoint server. This seems like a bad approach to me as it will influence everything .NET that is using that locale on that server (and only my SharePoint site) and the user executing the code (or app pool account when elevating) needs access to c:\windows\globalization.

Update:
I have worked with the Antons approach (as referenced above) and it turned-out to cause a couple of issues for User Profile synchronization such as editing of user profiles via Central Administration is no longer possible. So I used a custom PageAdapter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.pageadapter(v=vs.90).aspx) instead to modify the date format.

Comment: Why is changing the locale to something that uses the dd/MM/yyyy date format not an option?
The idea of changing the settings for the en-US Locale, while appealing to the rest of the world, seems a bad idea.

Comment: Because changing the locale changes a lot of other things as well. E.g. month and week day names, currency and so on.

Comment: what about using en-AU or en-NZ, names of days are all the same, spelling is 'right' :P ;) you get dd/MM/yyyy formatted dates and they still use $ for currency